# May I label with a monospaced typeface?

Tags: enumerate, labels, typewriter

Say I have an enumerate environment like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, enumitem, graphicx, hyperref, latexsym,  babel, blindtext, thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*},align=left,ref=\textbf{\alph*}]
        
        \item $a\in G$
        \item $\exists y(\theta(y)\wedge a\in y)$ 
        \item $\exists y(\forall z(z\in y\to z\subset y)\wedge a\in y)$ 
        \item $\forall z(z\in y'\to z\subset y')\wedge a\in y'$
        \item   $a\in y'$
        \item $a\in y'\to a\subset y'$
        \item $a\in y'\to a\in G$
        \item $a\in y'\to a\subset G$
        \item $a\subset G$ 
        \item $a\in G\to a\subset G$
        \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How may I obtain monospaced labels?

Comment: You should use `\texttt{\alph*}` to have a mono-spaced label for each `\item`.

Comment: Off-topic: Since you load the `amssymb` package, it makes no sense -- and it does you no good -- to load the `latexsym` package as well.